# Can SparkJava encoding all request data as UTF-8 by default?

Tags: java, utf-8, spark-java

I wonder if there is a way to configure SparkJava to encode all request data with a character set of my choice regardless of it comes from query parameters or POST data.  I have a number of web app's that I need to retroactively apply [STIG V-206410](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/web_server_security_requirements_guide/2022-09-20/finding/V-206410). I am looking for the most efficient way and hoping I need not go through every GET/POST/PUT handler and encode data manually with Java string encoding methods.

I looked at SparkJava's `before()` filter documentation, but I did not get the impression it is able to modify request data.